# How to get PUT params in rails controller when sent using jquery.ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

On click of button i have

```
(function() {
$("#btnStep2").click(function() {

    number = $('#btnStep2').attr('number');
     var dataString='number='+number+'&reserved='+$('#rd'+number).is(':checked')+'&environment=qa1';
    alert(dataString);
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/tnrepos/"+number,
    contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
    data: dataString, 
    success: function(data){ 
        alert("update successfully");

    }});
    return false;
});
});
```

on the server is see

```
    Started PUT "/tnrepos/12345" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-15 11:38:03 -0700
Processing by TnreposController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"12345"}
```

but i dont see other parameters passed ..

in the controller i print params

```
"action"=>"update", "controller"=>"tnrepos", "id"=>"12345"}
```

Why are not other parameters present ? I tested on firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/tnrepos/" + number,
    contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
    data: {data : dataString} ,
    success: function(data){ 
        alert("update successfully");

    }});
    return false;
});
});
```

You see the use of data: "{data : dataString}", above.

Now, your params[:data] will have the dataString.

> I would recommend passing them as "{number : number , reserved :
>   $('#rd'+number).is(':checked') } and accessing them on the controller
>   with their names like, params[:number], params[:reserved] and so on.

Try it and let me know!