# Rails Exchanging Data using RESTful API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, restful-architecture

I am trying to understand how to use POST/GET/PUT type of request to Exchange data from a Mobile Device and the API client.

I have a Form which has the following fields

- Name
- Age
- Sex
- Location

The above form is filled up on the mobile device after Client side validation and then i build a JSON as the following

```
{
  "name": "Harsha MV",
  "age": 28,
  "sex": "male",
  "location": "Bangalore, India"
}
```

Now i send a POST Request to the URL `http://example.com/users/create`

The Post request will contain a holder called `data` which will hold the `JSON` mentioned above.

**SERVER SIDE**

I check for the Authentication Tokens and then request for POST data and then look for the `data` holder and then expand the JSON and then serve the request `RESPONSE`

```
#simple example
def testing
    @data = JSON.parse(params[:data])
    render plain: @data.inspect

    # do all the manipulation to serve the request based on the DATA

  end
```

Do we need to bundle every Request of Data into the POST request into the `data` container.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Yes.
More info on:

1. [Back to Basics: HTTP Requests in Rails Apps](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-http-requests)
2. [Action Controller Overview : Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

and a similar question asked:

- [How to get PUT params in rails controller when sent using jquery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439927/how-to-get-put-params-in-rails-controller-when-sent-using-jquery-ajax)

Hope that helps.